# Отобразить число в шестнадцатиричной системе в виде строки

Tags: php

Допустим, есть число вида 0x1F08D.
Его нужно отобразить в виде строки в браузере прямо в таком же виде.

```
echo strval(0x1F08D); // выводит 127117<br>
echo (string)(0x1F08D); // выводит 127117<br>
```

Как вывести в браузере строку вида "0x1F08D"?

Comment: `echo "0x1F08D";`

Comment: echo '0x1F08D'; чем Вас не устраивает?

Comment: `echo dechex(127117); // 1f08d` Останется только сделать форматированный вывод как вам будет нужно.

Comment: `$num = 127117;`
`echo sprintf('Число в шестнадцатиричном виде 0x%X', $num);` выведет так как нужно 0x1F08D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорить о Вашем примере, то самый простой способ это взять в ковычки само число "0x1F08D", но скорее всего такое число приходит в переменную,например так $h = 0x1F08D,как быть в таком случае? 
Самый простой, на мой взгляд, вариант это использовать функцию `[sprintf][1]`.

> sprintf — Возвращает отформатированную строку

для форматирования так же используем *Описатель типа* %x, который будет форматировать аргумет в виде шестнадцатеричного числа.

```
$h = 0x1F08D;
$hexStr =sprintf('%x', $h);
```

Результат в $hexStr будет 1f08d.

В верхнем регистре - это параметр %X (большая).

Comment: `$num = 0x1f08d; echo sprintf('Число в шестнадцатиричном виде 0x%X', $num);` Модификатор %x вывод строчными, %X - прописными.

Comment: @iapetus, спасибо как раз правил ответ

Comment: @Konstantin Okhotnick Спасибо! Это то, что нужно